# Flask - avoiding having code in controller

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning Flask and all the router examples I see look like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
   name = request.args.get("name", "World")
   return f'Hello, {escape(name)}!'
```

I don't want any code in my controller except:

```
 @app.route('/')
 def hello():
    mycode.doHelloWorld()
    return mycode.sayHelloWorld()
```

I like my code to be reusable and testable and if it's in the Flask controller it's neither. 
Can someone point me to examples of using Flask with the business logic/code separate from the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try defining a function which returns a similar output given a `request` parameter like so:

```
def sayHelloWorld(request):
  name = request.args.get("name", "World")
  return f"Hello, {name}!"

@app.route("/")
def hello():
  return sayHelloWorld(request)
```

or based on the code you provided, you can create a class which contains reusable code snippets as static functions

```
class ReusableCode:
  @staticmethod
  def sayHelloWorld(request):
    name = request.args.get("name", "World")
    return f"Hello, {name}!"

@app.route("/"):
def hello():
  return ReusableCode.sayHelloWorld(request)
```

Comment: And I can have that code in a separate file/folder and include it (import) with __init__.py in the same folder right?